# How do I convert multiple pdf file to a single tiff file using java?

Tags: java, tiff, pdf-conversion

Can anyone help me to render the multi pages of Pdf file as a single Tiff Image file using **Java** code.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you considered so far, based on your Google searches?

Comment: I found Big Faceless Java Pdf Library and tried using their code,but it just renders first page of Pdf or seperate tiff file for each Pdf page.

Comment: I think GhostScript can render to TIFF, but I'm not sure it'll create a multi-image TIFF.  ImageMagick can almost certainly handle that part.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PDFBox library from Apache to read the file:

- http://pdfbox.apache.org/

Here is a full working example you can use to start:

- http://kickjava.com/src/org/pdfbox/PDFToImage.java.htm

Comment: @NewBie take a look at the 'main' method  of this class: http://kickjava.com/src/org/pdfbox/PDFToImage.java.htm  ... there is everything you need